# Json Path expression with AND (&&)

Tags: json, jsonpath

I am trying to find a jsonpath expression that it will return values only when the json array includes both categories "fiction" and "reference" and return nothing when json includes only one of them.

```
{
  "store": {
    "book": [
      {
        "category": "reference",
        "author": "Nigel Rees",
        "title": "Sayings of the Century"
      },
      {
        "category": "fiction",
        "author": "Herman Melville",
        "title": "Moby Dick"
      },
      {
        "category": "fiction",
        "author": "J.R.R. Tolkien",
        "title": "The Lord of the Rings"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

The following expression works when the json includes both categories but it still returns results even if the json has only one of the two categories.

```
$..book[?(@.category == 'fiction' || @.category == 'reference')]
```

If I try use && instead of || - I am getting an expression error.

```
$..book[?(@.category == 'fiction' && @.category == 'reference')]
```